# Perl Net::Telnet waitfor() hex charectors

Tags: regex, perl, hex, telnet

So I'm writing a script using Net::Telnet in perl... I want to waitfor() and match the hex charectors 01 (Ctrl+A) and 03 (Ctrl+C) as well as everything in between

how does on accomplish such a feat?

Answer (score 1):

Better is to wait for on non-ctrl characters(If you can throw some output from the terminal that displays this ctrl char it will help),

you can read all the buffer using prematch and match that is returned from waitfor call, which should contain all the characters that are printed.  Simple technique is to make $match undef and then get everything into $prematch.

Comment: the telnet connection im streaming to streams messages... all i do is log in an the messages start flying... the only way to tell when one starts and ends is the special hex charectors